# Antd validation on Input with hasFeedback and validateStatus

Tags: reactjs, antd

I was trying validation of input field with hasFeedback, validateStatus of ANT Design. If I set validateStatus = 'error' for now which I actually would set with state, I was able to get alert from onFinish function.  Am I missing something ?? I read documents and found onFinish will only trigger when validation has passed.
I want to validate that with my own validation rules and states.

```
function onfinish(){
   alert('hi')
 } 

 <Form
   form={form}
   onFinish={onfinish}
   >
     <Form.Item
       label="Mobile Number"
       validateStatus='error'
       hasFeedback
       name="mobileNumber"
       >
         <Input id='abc'/>'
     </Form.Item>
 </Form>
```

Comment: `validateStatus` dosent actually validate or perform anything. Its just a display for an easier way to display to a user what is going on. Changing his value will not change the functionallity/logic of the code. As the documentation implies `to customize your own validate status and message, without using Form`. Normaly, you require a Form to do such things, this allowed it to use it without a form. If you want to validatesomething, you require to do it either on submit (to change the state to chnage the `validateStatus`) or add `rules` on your `Form.Item`

Comment: @Lith Well, If this is the case I will have to look at how to write my own rules. Any link from your side ??

Comment: Writing patter in rule with regex helped.

Comment: Sorry for late response. When it comes to antd, i usually let it do all the validation. and when that is not an option - i do something really simple. Because regardless of how you validate it, its client sided. So you have to do validations on the server side too. And thats the important side. For client side i keep it simple so any user using it will have no issues, but anyone trying to break it will be able to but just on the client side. Glad that `regex` helped. I never heared of it, so ill take a look at it too for fun, thx.

Comment: yes, I have managed validations at the backend, applying the same to the client-side provides better user interactions :)

Comment: A simple for eg. rules={[{ message: "Not 10 digit", pattern: /^\d{10}$/,},]}